# How can I create a backup of my Exchange emails?

Tags: email, backup, exchange-server, archive

I have a Microsoft Exchange account through my college, and my mailbox is very close to full. I'd like to download the messages to my local machine and archive them so that I can access them later if needed.

It seems to me that I should do something using POP3, but I have no idea where to start.

Note: I am currently using Ubuntu 11.04, but I can boot into Win7 if necessary.

Comment: if you're using outlook you can go File->Export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a free product called MailStore that should do the trick. Find it at http://www.mailstore.com

Answer (score 1):

Use Outlook to connect to the mailbox and either expliiclty copy messages to a PST file or use AutoArchive feature to move the old message to an archive PST file.